# Why is my SurperView unresponsive when I remove a UIView SubView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview

I made a subview appear on my iOS app when a button is pressed. Then, I call a custom UIView from its class, menuView, and display that UIView on my main storyboard

The menuView appears fine on my Main Storyboard, but once I remove the subview, my SuperView (original view for main class for main view controller) is unresponsive, and I can't interact with anything.

What's wrong?

My Custom "menuView" UIView Class:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class menuView: UIView {

var view:UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "menuView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]

    addSubview(view)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    xibSetup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    xibSetup()
}

}
```

Main View Controller Class:

```
var myMenuView:menuView!

@IBOutlet weak var menuButtonOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    if menuButtonOutlet.title == "Menu" {

    if (myMenuView != nil) {
        self.myMenuView.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    self.myMenuView = menuView(frame: self.view.bounds)

    self.myMenuView.alpha = 0.75

    self.view.addSubview(myMenuView)

        menuButtonOutlet.title = "Back"

    } else {

          self.myMenuView.view.removeFromSuperview()

          menuButtonOutlet.title = "Menu"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

```
self.myMenuView.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

should become

```
self.myMenuView.removeFromSuperview()
```

in both places you have this line in *buttonPressed*.

**Explanation:**

Your myMenuView is a container in which you place the view you instantiate from your xib. In buttonPressed you remove only this inner(xib) view inside myMenuView and not myMenuView itself. Thus myMenuView remains on screen and swallows all the touches.